# MVVM and where to keep displayed fields/properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am learning MVVM by building a simple WPF calculator app.

In this simple app, there is one view (Main window), one ViewModel, and one Model (the calculation engine).

My calculator displays the current value of all previous operations, and the operations that got to that value.

For example a display might look like this:

1 * 2 * 3

```
    6
```

I am wondering if these should be saved as Properties on the ViewModel, Model, or both?

More general -- should the ViewModel contain only properties that exist on the Model, or this is not mandatory?

In this case i would save a CurrentValue and DisplayValue properties, just wondering which architecture layer should these belong to.

Answer (score 4):

In MVVM, ViewModels allow you to shape multiple entities from one or more data models or sources into a single object, optimized for consumption and rendering by the view. The below image illustrates the concept of a ViewModel:

[image]

The purpose of a ViewModel is for the view to have a single object to render, alleviating the need for UI logic code in the view that would otherwise be necessary. This means the only responsibility, or concern, of the view is to render that single ViewModel object, aiding in a cleaner separation of concerns (SoC). Concerns are distinct aspects of the application that have a particular purpose (i.e., concern), and keeping these aspects apart means your application is more organized, and the code more focused. Putting data manipulation code in its own location away from the view and controller, enforces SoC.

Using ViewModels in MVNM for finer granularity and better SoC leads to more easily maintainable and testable code. Remember, unit testing is about testing small units.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if these should be saved as Properties on the ViewModel, Model, or both?

In my opinion these should be property in `ViewModel`. Why these should be in the `Model` too? There is no benefit I can think of having this in `Model` too. These properties will only make sense to user in `View` so they should be displayed via `ViewModel` in the `View`. `Model` has nothing to do with it. At most you will have to pass expression `1 * 2 * 3` to `Model` and get results back, as you mentioned your engine is in `Model`.

> More general -- should the ViewModel contain only properties that exist on the Model, or this is not mandatory?

In general, a `ViewModel` should contain all the properties that have to be displayed in the View (via ViewModel). Regardless of the fact whether this property exists in `Model` or not. There is no rule that if this exists in `ViwModel` it should must be in `Model` too and vice versa. Generally `Model` is nothing more than representation of your business entities.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the model is not the place, where all your logic should be. The model is just the data for the view.

View model should contain any code needed to correctly adapt the model data to WPF display.

In your case you should work on an architecture a bit more.

There should be a class like `CalculatorProcessor`. View model may have properties for `CurrentExpression`, that, when a button `=` is pressed, are passed to a `CalculatorProcessor` to get processed (calculated) in sequece.

A result is also a property on a view model class that a view's controls are bound to.

Comment: Well there is not much of data going on in a Calc app. I am just collecting data through the UI and send to the (stateless) math "engine". These values are not stored there.

Comment: I have updated the answer, and it conforms with what you have. You are correct if you do just that.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel is specifically created for databinding purposes and as you expected contains properties needed by the view. In my opinion if you need any computed values to be displayed in the view, you can expose them as properties on view model.

Answer (score 0):

A model class is not only a business object, even if the model classes typically provide property and collection change notification events through change notification interfaces, so they can be data bound in the view, you can define an observable collection of instances of a class representing operations that represent he Ui interaction, so when a new op is inserted by the user, you add it to  the collection and the UI will automatically reflect it through the binding to an *templated listbox (for example)*